# The action webroot is not defined in controller AppController

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I have been running a cakephp application under

www.lernzentrum.de/kundenservice

for more than two years and everything worked fine. Now suddenly without any change from my side things go wrong: Any login results in an error:

"The action webroot is not defined in controller AppController"

You can try this yourself on my site. It looks like a routing error so I am giving my .htaccess files:

at /kundenservice/app/webroot/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

at /kundenservice/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

at /kundenservice/app/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

And here is a part of the error.log:

```
2016-08-30 14:42:46 Error: [MethodNotAllowedException] Method Not Allowed
Request URL: /kundenservice/lessons/spenden/6674
Stack Trace:
#0 [internal function]: LessonsController->spenden('6674')
#1 /mnt/web4/c3/63/51573863/htdocs/kundenservice/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(486): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(LessonsController), Array)
#2 /mnt/web4/c3/63/51573863/htdocs/kundenservice/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(187): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#3 /mnt/web4/c3/63/51573863/htdocs/kundenservice/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(162): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(LessonsController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#4 /mnt/web4/c3/63/51573863/htdocs/kundenservice/app/webroot/index.php(109): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#5 {main}
```

--- This was an exception thrown by the application while it was working as expected! --- The following is the mysterious new error which appeared out of the blue sky:

```
2016-08-31 19:20:25 Error: [MissingActionException]
Action AppController::webroot() could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'controller' => 'AppController',
  'action' => 'webroot',
)
Request URL: /kundenservice/app/webroot/service/cron
Stack Trace:
#0 /mnt/web4/c3/63/51573863/htdocs/kundenservice/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(187): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#1 /mnt/web4/c3/63/51573863/htdocs/kundenservice/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(162): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(AppController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#2 /mnt/web4/c3/63/51573863/htdocs/kundenservice/app/webroot/index.php(109): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#3 {main}
```

The Request URL should simply not contain /app/webroot.

The server is running on a Strato power web package so I have no access to httpd.conf. Any help would be much appreciated. If someone would like to give me support by phone (phone number is on my website) I would be happy to pay for that.

Best regards, Wilhelm

Answer (score 1):

I have a workaround, but I'm aware that it's not a good, "real", solution.

Apparently the source of this problem is the fact that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the URL in its redirected form (e.g. `/kundenservice/app/webroot/users/forgot` instead of `/kundenservice/users/forgot`). This happens only for routes other than `/`, though - the root page works. The reason is that apparently the `RewriteRule` in `/kundenservice/app/webroot/.htaccess` is causing this behavior - and it is only active when the URL doesn't point to an existing file or directory, and since `/` is directed to `/index.php` and that file exists, the problem doesn't appear in this case.

When searching on the Internet, I only found people asking the opposite: How can I have `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` modified by rewriting? - And the answer is that it is not supposed to be done and it is not possible (unless you use `[P]` or manually change the variable).

The problem appears to have started a while ago, probably due to some kind of version of configuration update by Strato - on my local machine, when testing the same scenario with XAMPP, everything worked as expected.

I was unable to find a solution for the root of this problem. However, I was able to find a workaround for the specific problem with CakePHP - namely, I just remove the confusing `app/webroot` part from the relevant `$_SERVER` variables before anyone gets to see them.

**In `.../app/webroot/index.php`, add the following lines directly under `<?php`:**

```
// Workaround for weird .htaccess rewriting problem
// Whenever both the rule in /.htaccess and /app/webroot/.htaccess are active,
// for some reason the actual URLs sent to PHP are modified (they shouldn't be).
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace('/app/webroot/', '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'] = str_replace('/app/webroot/', '/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'] = str_replace('/app/webroot/', '/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']);
```

As said above, I know that this is not solving the root cause and it is an ugly solution, but it works for now.

(Another way might be playing with the `baseUrl` configuration in `config/core.php`, but then the opposite can happen - that the root route doesn't work and the others do, so one needs some more trickery here...)